# Understanding edit distance by recursion

Tags: algorithm

I am reading section "8.2.1 Edit distance by recusion" from Algorithm Design Manual book by Skiena. In this section I could not able to understand below two points.

- D[i,j-1]+1. This means that there is an extra character in the text to account for,so we do not advance the pattern pointer and pay the cost of an insertion.
- D[i-1,j]+1. This means that there is an extra character in the pattern to remove,so we do not advance the text pointer and pay the cost on a deletion.

Above two points mentioning about calculating insertion and deletion distance. I could not able to understand how this logic works. It seems that for every pair it is assuming insertion and deletion is needed. Am i right? Why 1 is added for every insertion and deletion? please explain how this logic works.

Below is the algorithm

```
    //we will pass two strings and lengths of those strings
    int string_compare(char *s, char *t, int i, int j)
    {
      int k; /* counter */
      int opt[3]; /* cost of the three options */
      int lowest_cost; /* lowest cost */
      if (i == 0) return(j * indel(’ ’));
      if (j == 0) return(i * indel(’ ’));

      opt[MATCH] = string_compare(s,t,i-1,j-1) + match(s[i],t[j]);

    // *** I could not able to understand below two lines.   ***
      opt[INSERT] = string_compare(s,t,i,j-1) + indel(t[j]); 
      opt[DELETE] = string_compare(s,t,i-1,j) + indel(s[i]);


      return( min(opt[Match],opt[INSERT],opt[DELETE])); //min function will return min of all three values
    }

    int match(char c, char d)
    {
        if (c == d) return(0);
        else return(MAXLEN);
    }
    int indel(char c)
    {
        return(1);
    }
```

Please explain with example.

This is not a duplicate question. I did research but i could not able to find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit distance recursive algorithm -- Skiena](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217877/edit-distance-recursive-algorithm-skiena)

Comment: My answer and comments on both answers here might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036622/how-and-why-does-this-code-work-finding-the-minimum-number-of-steps-to-change-o

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm took me a while to truly wrap my mind around.  Please be aware that I don't have that textbook in front of me, but I'll try to help with what I know.

### Explanation

Let's say we're evaluating string1 and string2.  I'm going to elaborate on MATCH a little bit as well.

Your statement, *"It seems that for every pair it is assuming insertion and deletion is needed"* just needs a little clarification.  The algorithm does not necessarily assume insertion and deletion are needed, it just checks all possibilities.  After it checks the results of recursive insert/delete/match calls, it returns the **minimum** of all 3 -- the best choice of the 3 possible ways to change string1 into string2.

*"Why 1 is added for every insertion and deletion?"* - You are adding 1 for every change to the string.  So, each level of recursion that requires a change will mean "add 1" to the edit distance.  However, if the letters are the same, no change is required, and you add 0.  This is shown in `match`.`*`  Each recursive call represents a single change to the string.

### A Goofy Example

If you look at the references at the bottom of this post, you can find some well worded, thoughtful explanations about how the algorithm works.  Sometimes that's not what you need.  This is kind of weird, but I occasionally find it helpful if I can personify the code.  With that in mind, I hope this helps.

Let's take an example, `string_compare("he", "her", 2, 3)`.  We are starting the 2nd and 3rd positions (the ends) of each string, respectively.  Here are some vocal expressions of what the function 'says' when it sends off the recursive calls the first time around:

- MATCH - *I'll handle 'e' and 'r'.  I'll add 1 since they are different, and you just get me the result of 'h' and 'he'.*
- INSERT - *Let's find out how many changes we need if we insert a character into string1.  We'll of course insert a matching character, so we can really just skip the 'r' in string2.  You evaluate 'he' and 'he', and I'll add 1 to whatever you get.*
- DELETE - *Let's find out how many changes are necessary if we skip the 'e' in string1.  This is a change, so I'll add 1 to whatever you get when you compare 'h' and 'her'.*

There are so many branches (this is exponential time complexity), that it is difficult to draw out every scenario.  However, you can see that the INSERT dialogue is comparing 'he' and 'he'.  In the following recursions, every possibility will be tested.  However, the MATCH will always be optimal because each character matches and adds 0.

Each recursive call runs through that conversation.  Compare the current characters and recur, insert a character into string1 and recur, and delete a character from string1 and recur.  In each recursive level, the minimum of these 3 is the path with the least changes.  That will carry up the stack to give you your answer.

I know it's an odd explanation, but I hope it helps.

Other than the possible duplicate already provided, there's a pretty solid write up about this algorithm (with code) [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-5-edit-distance/).

`*`That being said, I'm honestly not sure why your `match` function returns `MAXLEN`.  I would expect it to return 1 as shown in the [possible duplicate link from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217877/edit-distance-recursive-algorithm-skiena).

Comment: In Skienna's text, he goes on to describe how the longest common subsequence problem can also be addressed by this algorithm when substitution is disallowed. He achieves this by adjusting `match` to return an expensive value `MAXLEN` when the characters do not match (OP likely looked at the wrong definition of `match` I'm guessing). Because Skienna does not define these helpers (nor indicate that their definition is delayed) when he initially presents the `string_compare` function, it makes for somewhat of a clunky presentation in the text IMO.